# Mapping values from combineLatest to Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

Having this:

```
 Observable.combineLatest(localArray.map((i) => {
  return <Observable that returns $value> }))
  .map((statuses) => {
    return statuses.filter((status) => {
      return status.$value === CONDITION
    });
  }).subscribe((eligible: any[]) => {
...
```

Is it possible to map the results from the subscription back to the `localArray`? I'd like to know which `eligible` item belongs to which `localArray` entry...

Thanks for the help.

**I read somewhere that the order is preserved with `combineLatest`. However, mapping directly to the index with a `forEach` will not work since the `eligible` results might return different length than the `localArray` if the condition(s) are met.**

*I can always remove `.map()` and do the filtering in the `subscribe` block which will enable me to loop over the `localArray` and update with the `eligible` data directly as such: `localArray.forEach((ai, i) => { ai.eligible = eligible[i] })` for example...*

Comment: Hi again! First of all, why are you using combineLatest with the result of a mapped array? Wouldn't `Observable.from(localArray)` do what you need? Or there is a request made for each element in array?

Comment: Hi @BorisLobanov! Yeah there's a request to be made for each element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the code:

```
Observable
    // Turn an array, promise, or iterable into an observable.
    .from(localArray)
    // Map values to inner observable, subscribe and emit in order.
    .concatMap((arrayElement: any) => {
        // Returning an observable that returns a value
        return Observable.of(arrayElement);
    })
    // Emit only values that meet the provided condition.
    .filter((value: any) => {
        return value === 'Some condition';
    })
    // Reduces the values from source observable to a single value that's emitted when the source completes.
    // If you need the current accumulated value on each emission, try scan - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html
    // The second argument here is the seed, the initial value provided the first time reduce is called. (In this case, an empty array)
    .reduce((filteredValue: any, accumulatedFilteredValues: any[]) =>{
        accumulatedFilteredValues.push(filteredValue);
        return accumulatedFilteredValues;
    }, [])
    .subscribe((filteredValueArray: any[]) => {
        // Do something with the array of ordered, filtered values
    });
```

First, I created an observable to emit each arrayElement in `localArray` using [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html).

When each `arrayElement` is emitted, I map that `arrayElement` to an Observable that will return some `value` (in this case I just return the arrayElement). I'm using [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) because it will subscribe to the inner observable and emit their value once they complete, **in the order they are emitted**.

I use [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) to only emit a `value` that satisfies a condition. Filter takes a function that returns either `true` or `false`. If `true` is returned, the `value` will be emitted.

Finally, I use [reduce](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/reduce.html) to collect the `filteredValue` and add it to an array of `accumulatedFilteredValues`. Reduce takes a function as its first argument, and an optional seed as its second.

The function passed to reduce receives the most recent emission (filteredValue) as its first argument and an accumulated value as the second (the empty array [])

After applying these operators to the emitted values, the function passed to subscribe receives an array containing the filtered, ordered items from `localArray`.

[learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/) is an excellent RxJS resource with examples and descriptions of various operators.

If you're using RxJS >= 5.5, consider using the [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) instead. In that case, the code would look a little closer to this:

```
from(localArray).pipe(
        concatMap((arrayElement: any) => {
            return Observable.of(arrayElement);
        }),
        filter(value => {
            return value === 'Some condition';
        }),
        reduce((filteredValue: any, accumulatedFilteredValues: any[]) => {
            accumulatedFilteredValues.push(filteredValue);
            return accumulatedFilteredValues;
        }, [])
    )
    .subscribe((filteredValueArray: any[]) => {
        // Do something with the array of ordered, filtered values
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to judge with the little amount of information that you have given whether that is a good idea or not, but it certainly doesn't sound like it to me. The reason I say that is because mapping back to the `localArray` would create an implicit loop in your data stream. Perhaps that is exactly what you need, so that is up to you.

What you can do in this situation is simply also emit the `index` (or some other identifier) that helps you map back to `localArray` from the `combineLatest`.

Something like this.

```
Observable.combineLatest(localArray.map((i) => {
  return <Observable that returns $value> }))
  .map((statuses) => {
    return [i, statuses.filter((status) => {
      return status.$value === CONDITION
    })];
  }).subscribe((eligible: [number, any[]]) => {
    // eligible now is a tuple type where the left element is the index of the localArray
  });
```

Comment: `i` here is undefined in the second `map`

Comment: So pass it along from wherever you do have access to `i`, or pass anything else downstream that helps you reference the thing you want to update. That's the point. Your code is broken in the first place, so don't take my example to literally.